# Else statement gets ignored when using multiple if else statements in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

My problem statement is creating a list with numbers between 1 to 30 using list comprehension with conditions like:
list should contain **a** if number is divisible by 15 and **b** if number is divisible by 5 and the number itself if it is divisible by 3.

I ***must implement it using List Comprehension only*** so don't suggest other methods.

This was my initial approach:

```
list=["a" if i%15 is 0
else "b" if i%5 is 0
else i if i%3 is 0
for i in range(1,31)
]
```

This gives **syntax error** at **for** .

So I tried this:

```
list=["a" if i%15 is 0
    else "b" if i%5 is 0
    else i 
    for i in range(1,31)
    if i%3 is 0
    ]
```

But this ends up ignoring the first else condition and gives me the following output.

`[3,6,9,12,'a',18,21,24,27,"a"]`

Now I don't understand why the else condition is being ignored here. I am relatively new to python so can someone explain where I am making a mistake here. Like what would be the equivalent if else block code for what ***I*** have written **not** the correct one for my problem statement (I know that).

Also I don't understand why this would work.

```
list=["a" if i%15 is 0
    else "b" if i%5 is 0
    else i
    for i in range(1,31)
    ]
```

The output this gives is obviously not the right one for my problem statement but I am curious how not having an if condition at the end makes it work properly.

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare numbers

Comment: When you put `if i%3 is 0` after the `for` in the comprehension, it means any items not matching that predicate are left out of the list entirely.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: And what should be returned if the number is not divisible by 15, 5, or 3?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani output is supposed to be  [3,'b',6,9,'b',12,'a',18,'b',21,24,'b',27,'a']

Comment: Thanks @khelwood. makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that can be improved with your code:

- Don't name a variable `list`, that clashes with a built-in function.
- Don't use `is` for comparing numbers, use `==`.
- Don't use a list comprehension for such a large conditional, unless you extract it to a separate function.
- Don't nest conditional expressions, prefer `if-elif-else` when you have many conditions. This is probably the source of your problem!
- You're not handling the case when the number is not divisible by 15, 5 or 3.

This is what I mean, notice how the `if` at the right of the `range` filters all the values that we want to remove:

```
def test_value(i):
    if i % 15 == 0:
        return "a"
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        return "b"
    else:
        return i

lst = [test_value(i) for i in range(1, 31) if i % 5 == 0 or i % 3 == 0]
```

If you really, really want to do this in a single line it's still possible, but heavily discouraged - you should not nest and abuse conditional expressions like this:

```
lst = ["a" if i % 15 == 0 else "b" if i % 5 == 0 else i for i in range(1, 31) if i % 5 == 0 or i % 3 == 0]
```

It works as expected:

```
lst
=> [3, 'b', 6, 9, 'b', 12, 'a', 18, 'b', 21, 24, 'b', 27, 'a']
```

Comment: 1. I have changed the variable name.  2. I was using 'is' because my teacher said it was the recommended method. I will look into it. 3. Like I mentioned, we HAVE to use List Comprehension.

Comment: You must not use `is` for comparing numbers in Python, your teacher is wrong.

Comment: Just as a side note on is, it is used for comparing for identity, a is b is True if a and b are the same object, its used to check for None as in a is None, since None is a global object

Comment: What is the expected output? And what should be returned if the number is not divisible by 15, 5, or 3?

Comment: Nothing should be added to list if none of those conditions hold true.

Comment: Thanks @ÓscarLópez . It works as expected. I don't like this approach either but had to do it for the sake of an assignment. Could you please explain why you wrote two if conditions in the end.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I will accept it. I was just waiting for the explanation. Thanks again.

Comment: @MithiAkanksha I wrote a single condition at the end, we want to remove from the list all numbers that are not multiples of either 3 or 5.